# Removed old vanity and installed new vanity and there is limited space to install new P-trap

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drain, sink, p-trap

As noted, I have installed the new vanity, and the space between the new sink drain and the wall is very limited (4.5 inches to center of the new sink drain). I thought I could just go on the other side of the wall and cut off what I needed to allow enough space...but the other side of the wall is a 90 degree bend. Now I have to come up with a totally different solution to still provide the trap. Looking for options.

I thought maybe I could install a t-junction and cap off one end so I would at least have a straight connection on the other side of the wall, providing me the precious additional room I need for the trap.

Comment: need picture.   Also p traps don't have to be perpendicular to the wall.

Comment: If your new sink is a low-profile, close-to-wall one (4.5 inches sounds like it) AND its drain hole lines up very close to the wall connection, you might need a bottle trap instead of a P one.   A picture would help, I won't make this an answer til you give us a little more info.

Comment: I agree you need to provide better info, but there are *many* ways you can build a P trap and quite a few types of prebuilt ones.  Generally they can bend all ways, so you can use a 30, 45, 60 or 90 degree fitting to turn sideways and have the P trap loop to the side and back.

Comment: The drain of a sink is typically naturally at least 8" off the wall, so it's actually very difficult to run a drain pipe to an unusable location other than being too high up.

Comment: Tried to add pictures and you are right, it is 4.5 inches to the wall. The picture file was too large...

Answer (score 1):

It is normal to cut the drainage end of the trap tube to fit.

They come long and are intended to be trimmed to fit - that's the "male" part of the slip joint normally found on the output of the trap - similar joints and trimming are typically found between the sink tailpiece and the trap entrance, though specific cases vary.

There's also typically a range of motion from twisting the trap horizontally.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is with the  fitting from 2 inches to 1.5 inches + the tube and the compression collar...even with the tube cut to a minimum length doesn't allow enough room...